# AngularFireAuth and Ionic 5 login issue

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire, capacitor

I've been working on a new app for iOS and Android.
I'm developping it on **Angular 12** using **Ionic 5**, **Capacitor** and **Firebase 9**.

While I'm used to setting up auth pages (login/register/pwd reset) with AngularFireAuth, I'm having trouble doing the same with Ionic and Capacitor.
My pages, services and guards are working fine on browser but as soon as I run 'ionic cap sync', build on XCode and try to run on my iPhone, my login function doesn't run.

Here's my code so far:

**AuthService:**

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './authUser.model';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  userData: any;

  constructor(
    public afStore: AngularFirestore,
    public ngFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public router: Router,
    public ngZone: NgZone
  ) {
    this.ngFireAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
    });
  }

  // Login in with email/password
  SignIn(email, password) {
    console.log('signing in from service');
    return this.ngFireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }
```

**Login Page:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/auth.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})

export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    public router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  logIn(email, password) {
    this.authService.SignIn(email.value, password.value)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('signing in from page');
        if (this.authService.isEmailVerified) {
          this.router.navigate(['tabs']);
        } else {
          window.alert('Email is not verified');
          return false;
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        window.alert(error.message);
      });
  }

}
```

Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 6):

I spent days troubleshooting this.   I am using Ionic 6, @angular/fire 7, Angular 14 but I believe the fix is the same regardless.  Answer based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71630326/firebase-authentication-sticks-capacitor-ionic-on-ios)

There is a fix for this without downgrading @angular/fire.   It involves only a slight modification to your app.module.ts file.

See changes below to **provideAuth(() => getAuth())**

Before:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore,getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideStorage,getStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage())],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

After:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { getApp, initializeApp,provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideAuth,getAuth, initializeAuth, indexedDBLocalPersistence } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore,getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideStorage,getStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    //provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideAuth(() => {
      if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
        return initializeAuth(getApp(), {
          persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
        });
      } else {
        return getAuth();
      }
    }),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage())],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have downgraded like so and then no issues. But this is super disappointing since we cannot use great new features and performance improvements of the latest Firebase now with Ionic native iOS apps.

```
npm un @angular/fire firebase

npm i @angular/fire@6.1.5  firebase@8.9.0
```

Note: You need to change the imports like so on all the places too:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cocoapods import pods/FirebaseAuth

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I did, but it doesn't seem to change a thing