# Angular / Ionic mobile app ios does not fetch from Firebase using angularfire

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to test a little Ionic/Angular sample app on an iOS Emulator.

On the web, all the requests to firestore using angularfire work perfectly fine.

Somehow if I try to execute the same app on the emulator, it keeps loading for the response of the request (if it was a empty response it would say that no results could be retrieved).

[image: Fetching results forever]

What is going on? Do i need to set something specifically for the Emulator to work and perform requests to Firestore?

Comment: Open up the console in the safari dev inspection or look up the error logs in xcode

Comment: Have you added the firebase config for an IOS app?

Comment: @Guiditox yes, the firebase connection works as a authentication request is successfully performed but the firestore request does not work

Comment: Ok, as minsha said, we need to see more information. Please share the safari console with the error (Develop => Your computer => The simulator)

Comment: @Guiditox there is just one Error displayed in the Console: 

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'gapi.iframes.getContext')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { initializeAuth, indexedDBLocalPersistence } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
 apiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
 authDomain: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
 databaseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
 projectId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
 storageBucket: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
 messagingSenderId: 
 process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
 appId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
});


function whichAuth() {
  let auth
  if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
    auth = initializeAuth(firebaseApp, {
      persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
    })
  } else {
    auth = getAuth()
  }
  return auth
}

export const auth = whichAuth()
const db = getFirestore();

export const auth = whichAuth();
export { firebaseApp, db };
```

Then in your component, cal your method like this  `await signInAnonymously(auth);`. Don't forget to import the `auth` we exported at the top.

Comment: How to do this with AngularFire?

Comment: @Sampath did you solve this? I have the same error using AngularFire

Comment: @ErnestoSchiavo You can see my workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69870562/1077309

Comment: Guys, any other solution beside downgrade to version 8?

Comment: After an Upgrade to Firebase 9.6.0 and AngularFire 7.2.0 this did indeed solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @ejro what is 'app' in your this line of code? initializeAuth(app, {
      persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
    }) ?  can u plz full app.module.ts ?

Comment: @MoblizeIT 'app' refers to 'firebaseApp'. I've updated the snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

*[Edit: updated with instructions Firebase JS SDK version 9 (modular)]*

This error occurs because Firebase Auth incorrectly detects its environment as a normal browser environment and tries to load remote Google APIs, which results in the error you see in the console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'gapi.iframes.getContext')
```

Fortunately, Firebase Auth already has logic to handle running in Cordova/Ionic apps, you just need to tell it which platform it's on.

**For Firebase JS SDK version 9 (modular)**

Simply import the Cordova Firebase Auth implementation:

```
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
```

**For Firebase JS SDK <9 or the compatibility modules (auth/compat)**

In `capacitor.config` set `server: { iosScheme: "ionic" }`:

```
// capacitor.config.json
{
  "server": {
    "iosScheme": "ionic"
  }
}
```

There's a check in the `auth/compat` [library here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/4983f4d5a0dc385c5b3e042ace44c8204d3cce81/packages/auth-compat/src/platform.ts#L54) which, when it sees the URL scheme `"ionic://"`, uses its Ionic/Cordova loading logic, and otherwise falls back to normal browser logic which fails with the error above.

Recent versions of Capacitor changed the URL scheme to `"capacitor://"` which fails this test but you can override it in your `capacitor.config` file (see the config option [`iosScheme`](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config)).

(See also @alistairheath's [comment here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3087#issuecomment-1063822400)).

Answer (score 1):

Been struggling a lot with this issue too but I managed to fix it. For those who need help here's my code.

You can delete all Firebase related imports from `app.module.ts` since this solution only uses Firebase.
The packages `rxfire` and `@angular/fire` can be removed from your `package.json`. The only dependency I have is `"firebase": "^9.6.1"`.
I used observables for the getObject and list functions since that's what I'm used to and I didn't want to rewrite my original code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { environment } from '@environment';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { Auth, getAuth, indexedDBLocalPersistence, initializeAuth, signInWithCustomToken } from 'firebase/auth';
import { Database, getDatabase, onValue, orderByChild, query, ref } from 'firebase/database';
import { Observable, Observer, from } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseService {
  private readonly database: Database;
  private readonly auth: Auth;

  constructor() {
    const firebaseApp = initializeApp(environment.firebase);

    if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
      initializeAuth(firebaseApp, {
        persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
      });
    }

    this.database = getDatabase(firebaseApp);
    this.auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
  }

  connectFirebase(firebaseToken) {
    return from(signInWithCustomToken(this.auth, firebaseToken));
  }

  disconnectFirebase() {
    return from(this.auth.signOut());
  }

  getObject<T>(path: string): Observable<T> {
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<T>) => {
      const dbRef = ref(this.database, path);
      const listener = onValue(dbRef, snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        observer.next(data);
      });

      return {
        unsubscribe() {
          listener();
        }
      };
    });
  }

  public list<T>(path: string, orderChildBy?: string): Observable<Array<T>> {
    return new Observable<Array<T>>((observer: Observer<Array<T>>) => {
      const dbRef = ref(this.database, path);
      const dbReference = !orderChildBy ? dbRef : query(dbRef, orderByChild(orderChildBy));

      const listener = onValue(dbReference, snapshot => {
        const data = Object.values<T>(snapshot.val() || {});
        console.log(path, data);
        observer.next(data);
      });

      return {
        unsubscribe() {
          listener();
        }
      };
    });
  }
}
```

For those who can't see the error message thrown by firebase try the following command in your Safari console to see the error.

```
window.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

The real problem: firebase-js-sdk on mobile iOS assumes google API (gapi) exists on the window, even when it isn't used.

**I found a work around: Mock window.gapi before using firebase auth login:**

```
window['gapi'] = {
  load: (name: string) => Promise.resolve(),
  iframes: {
    getContext: () => {
      return {
        iframe: {
          contentWindow: {
            postMessage: (message: any) => {
              console.log("gapi iframe message:", message);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
} as any;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me... Only remove the errore message...

Comment: I also found I needed to hide and show the firebase ui (open and close then re-open a modal in my case). Real hacky I know. But that plus the gapi code fixed it for me.