# Angularfire does not work on ionic capacitor app on ios

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, angularfire, capacitor

I am using ionic with capacitor and angularfire. It works fine but does not work on ios. On ios I don't see any error - just the firebase call that never returns anything. Below is my package.json and other relevant info.

ionic.info:

```
ionic info    

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.18.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.9.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.1.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.1.4
   @angular/cli                  : 12.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 3.3.2
   @capacitor/android : 3.3.2
   @capacitor/core    : 3.3.2
   @capacitor/ios     : 3.3.2

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms : android broken, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.4) : 0.15.3
   native-run                             : 1.5.0

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : ios-sim/9.0.0 darwin-x64 node-v14.17.0
   NodeJS     : v14.17.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 7.24.0
   OS         : macOS Monterey
   Xcode      : Xcode 13.1 Build version 13A1030d
```

Package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.3.2",
    "@capacitor/app": "^1.0.6",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^1.0.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.3.2",
    "@capacitor/device": "^1.1.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^1.1.3",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^3.3.2",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^1.1.3",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^1.1.6",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^1.0.6",
    "@capacitor/storage": "^1.2.3",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera-preview": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/contacts": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.12",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera-preview": "^0.12.3",
    "cordova-plugin-contacts": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.10.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inapppurchase": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-purchase": "^10.6.1",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^6.0.3",
    "firebase": "^9.5.0",
    "forcejs": "^2.2.1",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "xcode": "^3.0.1",
    "xml-js": "^1.6.11",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.3.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  }
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  ],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The code that never executes and no error in catch block is below. Same works just fine on android:

```
 const resp:any = await this.dataSvc.getSeedConfig()
 console.log("seed config is::" + JSON.stringify(resp))
```

So the above code does not go to the catch block and does not print the seed config on ios. Works fine on android.

Also on ios it works using live reload using

```
ionic capacitor run ios -l --external
```

so if i run it using xcode then it does not work. not sure what is blocking in that specific case

Comment: I have the same error only on IOS.

Comment: did you get any error in the log?

Comment: nope no error in firebase logs or ios logs or anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Already answered this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70594992/5701521 but could be useful to answer it here as well.

Been struggling a lot with this issue too but I managed to fix it. For those who need help here's my code.

You can delete all Firebase related imports from `app.module.ts` since this solution only uses Firebase.
The packages `rxfire` and `@angular/fire` can be removed from your `package.json`. The only dependency I have is `"firebase": "^9.6.1"`.
I used observables for the getObject and list functions since that's what I'm used to and I didn't want to rewrite my original code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { environment } from '@environment';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { Auth, getAuth, indexedDBLocalPersistence, initializeAuth, signInWithCustomToken } from 'firebase/auth';
import { Database, getDatabase, onValue, orderByChild, query, ref } from 'firebase/database';
import { Observable, Observer, from } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseService {
  private readonly database: Database;
  private readonly auth: Auth;

  constructor() {
    const firebaseApp = initializeApp(environment.firebase);

    if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
      initializeAuth(firebaseApp, {
        persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
      });
    }

    this.database = getDatabase(firebaseApp);
    this.auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
  }

  connectFirebase(firebaseToken) {
    return from(signInWithCustomToken(this.auth, firebaseToken));
  }

  disconnectFirebase() {
    return from(this.auth.signOut());
  }

  getObject<T>(path: string): Observable<T> {
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<T>) => {
      const dbRef = ref(this.database, path);
      const listener = onValue(dbRef, snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        observer.next(data);
      });

      return {
        unsubscribe() {
          listener();
        }
      };
    });
  }

  public list<T>(path: string, orderChildBy?: string): Observable<Array<T>> {
    return new Observable<Array<T>>((observer: Observer<Array<T>>) => {
      const dbRef = ref(this.database, path);
      const dbReference = !orderChildBy ? dbRef : query(dbRef, orderByChild(orderChildBy));

      const listener = onValue(dbReference, snapshot => {
        const data = Object.values<T>(snapshot.val() || {});
        console.log(path, data);
        observer.next(data);
      });

      return {
        unsubscribe() {
          listener();
        }
      };
    });
  }
}
```

For those who can't see the error message thrown by firebase try the following command in your Safari console to see the error.

```
window.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade your angularfire to v7.0  it might work with firebase v9.

Comment: i thought it is a capacitor 3 issue but will give a try

Comment: actual my angularfire is already v7. take a look in the package.json above.

Comment: please you comments as comments and answers as answers

Answer (score 0):

in my case i folow this link: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3087#issuecomment-990599459

I was also having this issue when building for an iOS emulator and actual iOS device, but adding this to the app.component.ts worked for me.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { indexedDBLocalPersistence, initializeAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    const app = initializeApp(environment.firebase);
    if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform) {
      initializeAuth(app, {
        persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This is where I found the fix and a sample code

Comment: how would your app.module.ts would look like in this case? as initialize code usually go there

Comment: sorry, actually this fix was in app.component.ts

Comment: this part was the correction:
I added this
initializeAuth(app, {
        persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
      });

Comment: i know but can you plz share your app.module.ts ?