# React Native TypeError: undefined is not a function signInAnonymously() Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am new to React-Native. I'm getting the above error in my signInAnonymously function with Firebase Auth. Everything seems to be connected as I'm getting a return of `null` in `onAuthStateChanged`

Here is my code:

```
const handleOnBoarding = () => {
  FIREBASE_AUTH.signInAnonymously()
    .then(() => {
    console.log("User signed in anonymously");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    });
};
```

Here is the error:

[image: error]

How can I solve this?

Adding Firebase Config Code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXX",
  authDomain: "XXX",
  projectId: "XXX",
  storageBucket: "XXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXX",
  appId: "XXX",
};

export const FIREBASE_APP = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const FIREBASE_AUTH = getAuth(FIREBASE_APP);
export const FIREBASE_FIRESTORE = getFirestore(FIREBASE_APP);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear how you are using `FIREBASE_AUTH` as It's not defined in the code you post. You can use the following code as per the documentation of Firebase.

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

auth()
  .signInAnonymously()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User signed in anonymously');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.code === 'auth/operation-not-allowed') {
      console.log('Enable anonymous in your firebase console.');
    }

    console.error(error);
  });
```

Details are [Here](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage)

Some of the resources are here that could help you

1- [anonymous-login-in-react-native-apps-with-firebase](https://enappd.com/blog/anonymous-login-in-react-native-apps-with-firebase/129/)

2- [anonymous-auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth)

Comment: I've updated FIrebase Config Code.

Comment: @DavidHenry your code looks fine, try to add the configuration code in the file you are testing ( Screen File ).

Comment: I've added the initializeApp & getAuth imports to the screen I'm using and added the config file. However, I'm still getting the same error?

Comment: @DavidHenry checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69793220/1283345 and this also https://modularfirebase.web.app/common-use-cases/authentication/