# Firebase auth web SDK not working on Ionic iOS?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

My issue is the login with the email and password function works fine on android but on iOS, the promise is never returned ( nor failed ) when correct credentials are provided but it fails if I provide incorrect credentials. The login works on iOS with live reload simulating on an iOS device, but when installed with test-flight or via xCode promise is never returned nor rejected.

How can I debug it further or know what the underlying issue is?

```
onSubmit: async (values) => {
              try {
                const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
                auth.setPersistence(browserSessionPersistence);
               
                // Never called on IOS
                auth.onAuthStateChanged(() => {
                  console.log('I am here', auth.currentUser);
                  if (auth.currentUser) {
                    updateIsAuthenticated(true);
                  }
                });

                const userCred = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, values.email, values.password);
                //Never runs
                console.log('After Success', userCred);

              } catch (error) {
                // Runs when provided with false credentials
                setError('Error: Authentication failed');
                console.error('An error Occurred');
              } finally {
                console.log('Running Finally');
              }
            },

        });
```

Comment: Downgrading to a older version of firebase had fixed the issue for me as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69135263/angularfireauth-and-ionic-5-login-issue. I am still trying to figure out what the breaks it