# Ionic AngularFirestore issue in iOS release

Tags: ios, swift, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore for **chatting** in my Ionic application, Which is perfectly working in Android and also in iOS but just **while debugging** not in release.

My npm versions are:

```
"@angular/fire": "^7.0.2",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/analytics-firebase": "^5.37.1",

"cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^5.0.0",
"firebase": "^9.2.0",
```

App.module.ts

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';

AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence({synchronizeTabs: true}),
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
```

Code:

```
const chat = firebase.firestore().collection('messages').where('groupId', '==', groupId).orderBy('added', 'desc');

    chat.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
      this.chatRoomMessages = [];
      docSnapshot.forEach((v) => {
        this.chatRoomMessages.push(v.data() as BAChatMessages)
      })
    }, err => {
      console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
    });
```

REVERSED_CLIENT_ID CFBundleURLTypes:

[image]

**Can anyone please help me to fix it?**

Comment: What isn't working about the code you shared? When you step through it line by line in a debugger, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen as i said, i'm using firestore for chatting, everything is working fine when i serve app in iPhone but as i export archive the chatting module doesn't work and i'm unable to debug.

Comment: can you refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69870562/15774176 is it helpful?